# VBA: Decrease iterations of loop after an array item has been deleted?

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

In VBA for Excel:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(artMaster)
    For j = i To UBound(artMaster)
        If i <> j And artMaster(i).VDN = artMaster(j).VDN Then
            Call DeleteArrayItem(artMaster, j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

How can I decrease the iterations of the loop after I have deleted one of the array items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be much better off using WHILE loops instead of FOR loops. Also, you could store UBound(artMaster) in a variable.

```
Dim I As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim n as Integer

i = 0
n = UBound(artMaster)

Do While i <= n
    j = i + 1

    Do While j <= n
        If artMaster(i).VDN = artMaster(j).VDN Then
            Call DeleteArrayItem(artMaster, j)
            n = n - 1
        End If

        j = j + 1
    Loop

    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Any idea whether storing the upper bound in a variable actually reduces run time? I would've thought UBound would've essentially just accessed a property of the underlying array object, basically just dereferencing a variable anyway? I may be broadcasting my ignorance of the inner workings of VBA here..

Comment: That is not the reason for doing it. The idea is to make it clearer that the upper bound of the loop is being changed, by doing it explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

You can subtract 1 from your iterator. But that can be problematic and makes the code harder to understand.

Perhaps a better approach is to loop from the last item to the first (step -1). This way, your iterator remains valid as you delete items.

Comment: +1 I used to always use the iterator subtraction trick. I can attest to the difficulties that arise when the meat of your loop starts to get more complex (i.e. nested loops, or very long loops/internal function calls).