# Case loop terminates before deleting all values

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I am trying to get my code to loop through about 10,000 lines of integers in row K and delete rows based on values, my code works but will only do small parts at a time. Please advise.

```
'Delete unwanted accounts
Dim Lcell As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Lcell = TransSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
For a = 1 To Lcell Step 1
   Select Case Cells(a, 11).Value
      Case "1200", "652", "552"
         Cells(a, 11).EntireRow.Delete
   End Select
Next a
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807576/vba-decrease-iterations-of-loop-after-an-array-item-has-been-deleted

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a single delete on all the identified rows:

```
'Delete unwanted accounts
Dim rngDel as range
Dim Lcell As Long, v

Lcell = TransSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

For a = 1 To Lcell 
   v = Cells(a, 11).Value
    If v = "1200" or v = "652" or v = "552" Then
        If Not rngDel is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, Cells(a, 11).EntireRow)
        Else
            Set rngDel = Cells(a, 11).EntireRow    
        End If
    End If
Next a

If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Delete
```

Comment: Beautiful step using `Application.Union()`

Answer (score 0):

Try from the last row to the first one.  You are deleting rows so your numbering is being thrown off:

```
'Delete unwanted accounts
Dim Lcell As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Lcell = TransSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
For a = Lcell To 1 Step -1
   Select Case Cells(a, 11).Value
      Case "1200", "652", "552"
         Cells(a, 11).EntireRow.Delete
   End Select
Next a
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code

```
Cells(a, 11).EntireRow.Delete
a = a - 1
```

This will take care of the shifting that occurs because the row disappears.

---

On a side note, I personally use the following method to delete multiple rows. e.g. the rows I want to delete are stored in an `Variant` array `DelRows()`. You may obtain them dynamically at run-time. Here I manually assign some random rows.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim DelRows() As Variant
    ReDim DelRows(1 To 3)

    DelRows(1) = 15
    DelRows(2) = 18
    DelRows(3) = 21

    '--- How to delete them all together?

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(DelRows) To UBound(DelRows)
        DelRows(i) = DelRows(i) & ":" & DelRows(i)
    Next i

    Dim DelStr As String
    DelStr = Join(DelRows, ",")

    ' DelStr = "15:15,18:18,21:21"

    ActiveSheet.Range(DelStr).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: preferable to iterate backwards rather than manipulate the iterator variable :)

Comment: @DavidZemens, true true! just that the iterator variable might also be quite unstable here since it'll have to keep track of how many rows already deleted, u think?

Comment: I think it's a valid method: decrementing the increment variable keeps it sync'd with the rows collection (each `.Delete` reduces the `.Count` by 1) but I think it is inefficient (unnecessary extra operation inside a loop) and also maybe a bad habit because often we do a single `For i = ...` and use the one iterator `i` as an index to do different actions on multiple objects in parallel, in which case you would potentially get undesired results -- unless you add *yet another* variable for each object being iterated.

Comment: actually I wouldn't personally use either method. guess i should post my method in the edit as well. update in a minute

Comment: Sure that is another approach, personally I wouldn't use it though. The `For/Each` construct is generic so you use a same/similar method whether you're deleting rows in a worksheet or keys in a dictionary or items in a collection, etc.  Also, unless you know in advance what needs to be deleted, it seems likely that you have to do the iteration over the collection anyways.

Comment: Yup, hence, unlike this example the production code first goes through the sheet to create the generic string of to-be-deleted rows and then in a single operation deletes it. This is a bit more complicated than going row by row, but delete is a very expensive operation in Excel and for performance intensive stuff, it sometimes help. But +1 abt the point regd the `For/Each` construct.

Comment: Did you see Tim Williams' answer? That's another neat approach.