# vba loop performance too much time

Tags: performance, loops, excel, vba

I have **250.000 rows** and I wanted to erase all rows that have a 0 in col AR. This takes too much time using a filter and deleting only visible cells, so I wrote a code.  But still takes 1 minute for 1000 lines. So I will have to take 250 minutes!!! Besides after the first 6 minutes (6k lines) the number showed in AS3 (see code below) freezes, so I don't know if it's still running.

**Is there a way to do this more efficiently (using less time)?**

My code is:

```
Sub delrow()


Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual


With Sheets("bners")
LR3 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i3 = 3 To LR3
range("AS2")=i3
    a = Sheets("bners").Range("AR" & i3).Value
    If a = 0 Then
    Rows(i3).Delete
    Else
    End If
Next i3
End With

Application.calculate


End Sub
```

thanks!

Comment: Why are you setting ScreenUpdating to True before you execute the deletes?? Normally you set that to False at the beginning of the method and True at the end. The whole point is to not repaint Excel constantly. Change that and you should pick up a lot of speed. Is it still too slow after changing that??

Comment: it's the same in this case. takes a lot of time anyway.

Comment: You will get some saving by replacing For `i3 = 3 To LR3` by `For i3 = LR3 To 3 Step -1`.  With the downward loop, if you delete row 3, rows 4 to 250,000 have to be moved up even if most are to be deleted.  Also if you delete row 3, row 4 becomes row 3 and will not be checked.

Comment: FWIW, Not sure wha's different but I just it on 250k lines using the same code and took about a minute

Comment: Did you try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24665335/293078 ?

Comment: Don't loop at all.  Use autofilter on that column and delete the rows in 1 step.  Well 1 step per block.  250k rows is a lot.  Break them down in to 10k chunks and it will be faster than looping.  Another option is to filter the data so all of the 0s are at the top and count the number of 0s and delete only those rows.

Comment: One question please, `if a=0 then ` , will trigger when the cell is empty AND when the value 0 is in it. Wich one do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely `Step -1`.  But does that alone make it fast?
This batches the deletes 10 at a time (if needed now).

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws as Range

Sub delrow1()
  Dim LR3&, i3&, a&
  Set ws = Sheets("bners")
  LR3 = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i3 = LR3 To 3 Step -1
    a = ws.Cells(i3, "AR").Value
    If a = 0 Then
      Call delrow2(i3)
    End If
  Next i3
  Call delrow2(0) ' flush
End Sub

Sub delrow2(delRow&) ' deletes 10 rows at a time
  Static a1&(10), na1&
  Dim i1&, zRange As Range
  If delRow = 0 Then ' finish;end;flush
    For i1 = 1 To na1
      ws.Rows(a1(i1)).Delete
    Next i1
    na1 = 0
  Else ' store row in array a1
    na1 = na1 + 1
    a1(na1) = delRow
    If na1 = 10 Then ' del 10 rows
      Set zRange = Union( _
        Rows(a1(1)), Rows(a1(2)), Rows(a1(3)), Rows(a1(4)), Rows(a1(5)), _
        Rows(a1(6)), Rows(a1(7)), Rows(a1(8)), Rows(a1(9)), Rows(a1(10)))
      ws.Range(zRange).Rows.Delete
      na1 = 0
    End If
  End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked this method I found a couple weeks ago but didn't remember until last night http://goo.gl/NYtY9R that could easily be adapted for yours

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim F As Range, rKill As Range
    Set F = Range("A2:A250000")
    Set rKill = Nothing
    For Each r In F
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, "0") = 1 Then
            If rKill Is Nothing Then
                Set rKill = r
            Else
                Set rKill = Union(r, rKill)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not rKill Is Nothing Then
        rKill.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

To me very efficient in that it builds up into the Union and then deletes all at once instead of deleting one at a time.

Comment: `Set F = Range("AR2:AR250000")` , and not in the first column

Comment: ion fact starts at AR3, not 2 , sorry

Answer (score 0):

in the example , you `with sheets()` is totally useless, as you forgot every dot "." before the words `cells` or `range` or `rows`.

I'll try an other approach, by using two VBA arrays (not tested, and might memory overflow).
first array is original data before the macro.
second array is data after the macro

I won't delete rows, i just write my second array from the good lines of the 1rst array,
and then paste it over the sheet

```
Sub RowKill()

'Declaring Variables :
Dim MaxRows as long   'number of lines in the First Array
Dim NewRows as Long   'number of lines in the Second Array
Dim q as long         'simple loop counter
Dim i as long         'simple loop counter , for the purpose of copying line
Dim Rg As Range       'Range of the original Data (number of lines = MaxRows-2, because the Original example code starts at 3, not 1)
Dim Sh as Worksheet
Dim Array1() as variant 'First VBA Array
Dim Array2() as variant 'Second VBA Array



with Application
     .enableevents=false
     .screnupdating=false
     .Calculation=xlCalculationManual
end with

set Sh=thisworkbook.Sheets("bners")

with Sh
    MaxRows = .Range( .Rows.Count , 44).End(xlUp).Row ' note the .rows, and i read on cloumn 44 and not 1
    Set Rg = .Range( .cells(3,44) , .cells ( MaxRows,44) ) '44 is the column of .range("AR")
    'The Range Rg is important , later we delete the whole thing ^^
    Redim Array1 ( 1 to MaxRows, 1 to 44)  'Only if "AR" is your last column
    Array1 = Rg.value2 'if you work with dates or time format in your cells, please replace by : Array1 = Rg.value



    for q= 3 to MaxRows

        if Array1 (q , 44) <> 0 Then 'wasn't sure, because empty cells will trigger too, in wich case: <>"" would be better, or: If not IsEmpty( Array1 (q,44))    .....
            call CopyRowToSecondArray ( q , NewRows , Array2)
        End If

    next q

End With 'Sh

'Rg.delete  'old version


With Sh 
     .range ( .cells(1,1) , .cells (44 , NewRows).Value2 = Array2 ' again use .value, if you have date or time formating inside the data cells
     if NewRows<MaxRows then .range ( .cells(1,NewRows+1) , .cells (44 , MaxRows).Value2 = ""
End with

with Application
     .enableevents= True
     .screnupdating= True
     .Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic
end with

Set Rg = Nothing
Ser Sh = Nothing
Erase Array1, Array 2

End Sub


Sub CopyRowToSecondArray ( byval q as long , byref NewRows as long , byref Array2 as variant)
Dim i as long
NewRows=NewRows+1
Redim Preserve Array2 (1 to NewRows, 1 to 44)
for i = 1 to 44  'this entire for i loop, might be faster with unknown vba array function (i'm new), please share with me
     Array2 ( NewRows , i) = Array1 ( q , i )
next i
end sub
```

Maybe there is a better way to simply copy a whole line from one array to an other, i don't know...

The code is untested, and , I assumed 44 is the  last column (change only in loops and Rg if needed), so copy your work before testing my code.

Hope this helps, and is faster.